# How to change position of Price of Bundle Product Woo Commerce?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I am creating a bundled product in WOO Commerce using **YITH Plugin**. How to change the position of Price?
[image: I want to change the position as in the image]

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to functions.php of your theme,

remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 25 );

try by changing the value 25 which indicates the priority of the hook.The priorities are in the order

- @hooked woocommerce_template_single_title – 5
- @hooked woocommerce_template_single_price – 10
- @hooked woocommerce_template_single_excerpt – 20
- @hooked woocommerce_template_single_add_to_cart – 30
- @hooked woocommerce_template_single_meta – 40
- @hooked woocommerce_template_single_sharing – 50